# What does "you're comin' at my friends" mean?

Tags: meaning, definition

Does "you're comin' at my friends" mean:
"you blame my friends"
or
"you're trying to become my friend"
or something else?

Lyrics:

> You are somebody that we don't know
>   But you're comin' at my friends like a missile
>   Why are you mad?
>   When you could be GLAAD?
>   You could be GLAAD
>   Sunshine on the street at the parade
>   But you would rather be in the dark age
>   Just makin' that sign must've taken all night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You are being aggressive at my friends".

This is heightened by "like a missile" (an offensive weapon) and the line after. The singer is asking what has caused the person's aggression